# Cómo acceder al atributo de un objeto en PHP pasando como parametro un string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Cómo puedo acceder al atributo de un objeto sin conocer su nombre.

```
Object $registro->"atributoDesconocido"
```

Los atributos los tengo en un array aparte. Lo que necesito es algo similiar a lo que se hace con un array.

```
$registro[$variable]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si dices que el nombre de los atributos está almacenado en variables, simplemente llama la variable rodeada por {}

```
$atributo = 'color';
echo $obj->{$atributo};
```

Comment: Fué la solución!!! Gracias.

Comment: si la respuesta te funcionó, puedes marcarla como aceptada

Answer (score 2):

Acabo de encontrar una solución, pasando el objeto a un array.

```
 class myObj {
  public $a;
  public $b;
}
```

Ahora solamente tengo que hacer

```
$obj = new myObj();
$myArray = (array) $obj
```

Ya podré acceder de la siguiente forma.

```
$myArray['a'];
```

Espero le sirva a alguien más.